# How to figure out if some Kotlin standard library type is Serializable?

Tags: kotlin

In the following code, the `linkedSet` variable is of type `LinkedHashSet<Serializable>`:

```
val linkedSet = linkedSetOf(linkedSetOf(1, 2, 3), 2)
```

The first element of the resulting set is `LinkedHashSet<Int>`. Going up the hierarchy of `LinkedHashSet` I didn't find the `Serializable`. Same thing for `Int`.

Why does inheriting the `Serializable` isn't explicit? And how can I figure out that some type is `Serializable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually if you start with [`LinkedHashSet`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-linked-hash-set/index.html) its declaration is as follows:

```
expect class LinkedHashSet<E> : MutableSet<E> {
```

[`expect`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/platform-specific-declarations.html) however awaits an actual implementation and the actual implementation of this on the JVM is `java.util.LinkedHashSet`, which then implements `Serializable`:

```
@SinceKotlin("1.1") public actual typealias LinkedHashSet<E> = java.util.LinkedHashSet<E>
```

Regarding [`Int`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/index.html) it is a bit more complicated. There we do not see any `expect`. But we know `Int` can represent both: the Java primitive type `int`, but also the Java type `Integer`. The compiler actually uses now `java.lang.Integer` under the hood and that implements `Serializable` via `java.lang.Number`.

You can check the actual types at runtime, using something as follows:

```
val linkedSet = linkedSetOf(linkedSetOf(1, 2, 3), 2)
linkedSet.forEach { content ->
    content::class.java.interfaces.joinToString {
        it.simpleName
    }.also {
        println("${content::class.java}: $it")
    }
}
```

Regarding how you can find out whether a "standard" library type implements `Serializable` or not: besides consulting the documentation, you can just declare the type explicitly if you want to ensure serializable types, i.e.:

```
val linkedset : LinkedHashSet<Serializable> = ...
```

You will then get compile time errors if something isn't serializable (except you do an unsafe cast in which case you basically fool the compiler or yourself).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IDE, you can easily check that for any type thanks to Lint:

[image]